# How can I use GPU on Mac vs code?

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio, pytorch, gpu

this is a beginner question.
I don't know how to use GPU on Mac vs code. Would anyone tell me how to do that from beginning?

I'm using MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020).
I tried to use pytroch, and run `torch.cuda.is_available()` but returns False.
I already installed torch and know how to use Jupyter extension on vs code.

I used Google colab, so I don't get ideas about local GPUs...

Comment: You can’t: MacBookPros do not have CUDA compatible GPUs.

Comment: @KonradRudolph 
thanks for your comment.
Then, how MacBookPro users do DNN training???

Comment: You need to run it elsewhere. On a cluster, on cloud computing resources, etc. Of course you *could* run it on a MacBook using the CPU but doing so would be too slow to be practical.

Comment: I was actually wrong, pytorch supports Apple’s GPU backend (Metal). See e.g.: https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-pytorch-on-apple-m1-chip-with-gpu-acceleration-3351dc44d67c — Of course you need to target the appropriate device, not CUDA.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue but here's how you can check if Metal is available on your Mac:

```
print(torch.backends.mps.is_available())
```